# Sharepoint 2010 Site collection url

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We have created the following sharepoint 2010 site collection using an internal url.

http://pdc.wlroot.companyname.com/sites/Extranet

How would i map a url another domain http://extranet.companyname.com to this?

OR

I think it would be easier to change the site collection url from 
/sites/Extranet
to
/
-How would I do this?

thanks in advance,
Jason

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is to Extend the Web Application. Below steps will help to achive this.

1. Go to SharePoint 2010 Central Administration Site - >
2. Click Application Management
3. Select Manage Web Application
4. Select your Application (http://pdc.wlroot.companyname.com/sites/Extranet) in the List
5. Select Extend in the Ribbon Bar
6. You will get a Popup for Extend Web Application to another IIS Site.
7. Fill in the Options & specify you new host Header. You should be good to go.

For more Information on this topic visit [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287954(office.12).aspx#Section2)